# (openldap) ldappasswd command doesn't work with uid, but does with cn=full name

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am attempting to add passwords to 1300 users in my OpenLDAP server for work.

I can add a password to a user if I utilize the following command

```
ldappasswd -s newpasswd -w adminpw -D "cn=admin,dc=school,dc=private" "cn=test user,dc=school,dc=private"
```

I have 1300+ people that I am adding passwords for though, and some users have duplicate names but different uids.

I do the following command when trying to use the UID but it doesn't find the user.  The command is the same except for switching cn=test user  for uid=testu.

```
ldappasswd -s newpasswd -w adminpw -D "cn=admin,dc=school,dc=private" "uid=testu,dc=school,dc=private"
```

According to all of the guides I've seen online this should work.  Why do I get a No such object (32) error?

Just to note I am working on a test server for the moment.  The user is made up for test purposes.  "cn=Test User" "uid=testu" "uidNumber=1001" The user is in the base of the ldap "dc=school,dc=private"  There is one group called "People" with a gid=501

I used http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/02/openldap-add-users-groups/   for a guide along with https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-and-use-ldap-servers-with-openldap-utilities#various-other-ldap-commands

I am an ldap novice when it comes to adding users/modifying them, but I did build the servers, did set up replication between them and added
 TLS encryption for them.

Comment: I've never seen a guide that says this should work. You have to supply the complete DN, not just make soemthung up.

Answer (score 0):

Each LDAP entry is a collection of attributes which are name-value pairs.  Usually, you pick a single attribute in the form `name=value` as the Relative Distinguished Name (RDN) of the entry.  Wisely, you pick an attribute with a unique value.

All entries are nodes in a Directory Information Tree (DIT).  The path to an entry consists of a sequence of RDNs joined by commas in leaf-to-root (left-to-right) order by convention.  This path is called Distinguished Name (DN) and is used to identify the user in the DIT.

As you chose the RDN to be `cn=test user` you can't address the user with DN `uid=testu, dc=school, dc=private`, even though an attribute `uid` with value `testu` is part of the user entry.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thank you for the explanation. I assumed that      `cn=test user`   would be swappable for   `uid=testu`

Comment: On a tangent, but related - I am finding it odd that when I imported the user, it was imported with `dn: cn=testu,dc=school,dc=private` on the top line of the ldif with an added `cn=test user` in the following lines of the ldif file.  On import it seems that it swapped `cn=testu` for `cn=test user` in the DN.  I imported the ldif with the `dn: cn=testu,dc=school,dc=private` because it was a unique identifier and I know we have students with the same first & last name because we ran into that issue when creating their entries in the old Novell ldap we are shifting away from.

Comment: cn is a multi-valued attribute, so no problem having more than one value.  Import from an LDIF file will honor the specified dn.  Make sure your LDIF file has the RDN value as an attribute value, too.